# How is this Qt boilerplate constructor not recursive?

Tags: c++, qt, recursion

So when you create a standard Qt5 widget application, this is the boilerplate code for the `QMainWindow` subclass:

**`mainwindow.h`**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**`mainwindow.cpp`**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

So the class has an instance of itself, that seems fine. But then that instance itself would have an instance of itself, which in turn would have an instance of itself...

How does this not lead to an infinite recursion of classes containing themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not the same classes. `MainWindow` is declared in the global namespace, while the `ui` member is of type `Ui::MainWindow`, which is declared in the `Ui` namespace. You can see the declaration of this class by looking at `ui_mainwindow.h`.

Since these are two different types, no recursion will happen, since `MainWindow::~MainWindow()` will not be called from within itself.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but where is the definition of the UI class? Other than these two files theres only the main file and a `.ui` file thats just the UI of the window in XML format

Comment: Nevermind, after RTFM, I found out that `Ui::MainWindow` is autogenerated by the `uic` tool which compiles `.ui` files into C++ code. So your answer removed all doubts from my mind! It's been a while since I've used C++ :)